# Prover9 installation error on Windows

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I tried to install Prover9 on my Windows system. But after completion of the installation procedure when it is supposed to launch the application. I'm getting the following error:

[Prover9error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzXnN.png)

When I tried to search for that log file, there was no such file present at that location.
Please help if anyone has come across something like this and knows how to solve it.

[P.S.: I could find this error on the internet.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also had a problem installing the prover9 due to the Missing MSVCP71.dll however i have overcome it by get the prover9-Mace-version4 installed. to solve the error follow this instruction

"If you are using Windows 7 32-bit then you need to put both dll files inside Windows/System32 folder as shown in the screenshot below."

If you are using Windows 7 64-bit then you need to put both dll files inside the Windows/SysWOW64 folder as shown in the screenshot below.

hope it solve ur problem

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem by doing the same. Thanks for the helpful answer though.